# Dropdown parent menu link not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I m working on wordpress with bootstrap. wp menu dropdown parent link not working in mobile.

Here is the js:-

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($) {

   $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
       $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
     },function() {
       $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();
   });

   $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
       location.href = this.href;
   });

 });
</script>
```

kindly advice me any solution ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hover on a touch device, could try adding focus maybe or even an click function instead of hover?

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').focus(function() {}
```

or

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').click(function(){}
```

Or use a css fall back. If you put a transition on it, it can give you the same slide effect.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown:focus .dropdown-menu, .dropdown:active .dropdown-menu{
      display block;

}
```